# Is inline equals #define function?

Tags: c++, optimization, c-preprocessor, inline

Does `inline int GetNumber(int i) { return mNumbers[i]; };` equals to: `#define GetNumber(i) mNumbers[i]` from machine instruction perspective?

`mNumbers` defined this way: `std::vector<int> mNumbers`.

Comment: Often, yes, but in general, no.

Comment: The `#define` is not type safe.  There is control over passing different types or returning different types.  One could pass a structure to a `#define` that was meant for an integer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes but the compiler should yell at compile time becasue if someone passes for exmaple: `struct Foo sF; GetNumber(sF)` so the compiler will throw an error becasue he will see: `mNumbers[sF]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Preprocessor macros are replaced like a query-replace in a text editor, and before the code is passed to the compiler proper. Inline function *may* have their code inserted in place on the call-site. While they may seem similar, it's quite different.

Comment: And in the event the function code does get inserted in the call site, it will be the same machine code like if it where the preproccesor definition?

Comment: @UnTraDe Yes, in the end it **might** be the same machine code. But unlike when using a macro it's already compiled (intermediate) code that is inserted. With a macro the actual C++ code *as text* is there already and which the compiler has to actually compile.

Comment: @UnTraDe Also, you have to remember that the `inline` keyword is only a hint. It's completely up to the compiler it if will actually inline the call.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: re "inline keyword is only a hint", presumably you meant that "with respect to machine code inlining, inline keyword is only a hint". if hinting was all then the keyword would probably not even have made it into the language. but as it happens there is (of course) a guaranteed (different) effect.

Answer (score 4):

No.

`inline` has one guaranteed effect: it allows you to define the same function (identically) in more than one translation unit, and then requires the function to be defined in every translation unit where it's used.

`inline` also serves as a **hint** that calls of the function should be inlined at the machine code level, but

- that hint can be freely ignored, and in case of a recursive function logically must be ignored for some calls,
- machine code call inlining is not the same as macro expansion, in particular the macro doesn't respect scopes.

Perhaps the most important advice I can give you here is to **stop fretting about micro-optimization**. It's premature. And premature optimization is evil.

Comment: I didn't ask about the optimization part... I'm just trying to understand how the **inline** keyword works...

Comment: @UnTraDe: your question is tagged "optimization", presumably by you, and you now say that you "didn't ask about the optimization". that's a **self-contradiction**. did someone else impersionate and change your question (since there's no record of others editing the question), or are you here trying to lead others to believe that which you know is false -- which is it.